# How to link against libuuid when cross compiling on Ubuntu for target Pico Zed Arm

Tags: arm, cross-compilation, uuid

My compile line is:

```
$GCC -O0 -o ONVIFTargetServiceDiscovery ONVIFTargetServiceDiscovery.o Utilities.o Logger.o Socket.o -luuid -lpthread
```

Where: `GCC="arm-linux-gnueabi-g++"`

When executed, this results in

> /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: canot find -luuid"

And, in fact, the library does not exist in `/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7`. I have been unsuccessful at locating packages containing `libuuid` for cross-compiling on Ubuntu targeting the ARM processor that will install.

I am relatively new to Linux development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install the development package for the armhf version of libuuid, like so:

```
$: sudo dpkg --add-architecture armhf
$: sudo apt-get update
$: sudo apt-get install libuuid-dev:armhf
```

This should result in the necessary binaries for the armhf build of libuuid being installed to the appropriate location for cross-compiling.

Comment: I got subsequent errors on the apt-get update due to dependencies, but the suggested solution using dpkg switch solved the stated problem.  Thanks.

Comment: libuuid-dev is now uuid-dev. The solution doesn't work anymore. It now wants to uninstall all the other packages of the system (Ubuntu Xenial). What to do now?!